# Adding a legend for x-axis tick marks?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to add a legend for the x-axis tick labels in ggplot2?

As a very easy example:

```
df <- data(economics_long, package = "ggplot2")

df$variable <- factor(df$variable)
levels(df$variable)  


ggplot(data = df, aes(x=variable)) +
geom_bar()
```

The Barplot obviously doesn't make a lot of sense, but I would just want to add a legend, where I specify the abbreviations of the x-axis-tick marks, because with my data, the full labels would be too long on the x-axis itself.
Is this possible?

Comment: What is your 'y' variable.  The 'x' is factor class

Comment: Is it necessary to specify that? I only care about the x-axis tick marks. As I said, the ggplot doesn't make sense, but the x-axis does bring my point across.

Comment: `The Barplot obviously doesn't make a lot of sense`, it is taking the count which is the same for each of the levels `table(df$variable)`

Comment: Yes, I know. It doesn't matter though for just the labels of the x-axis? It's not possible for me to post my real data here and to recreate the full barplot is overly complicated to recreate for an example, where only the x-axis itself and the labels there are relevant. 
If it is too irritating, I can also change it, the solution to my question would be the same though, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. To get a legend for your x axis variable you could map `variable` on `fill` and remove the fill colors, legends key, ... like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- economics_long

labels <- c(pce = "pce = personal consumption expenditures", 
            pop = "pop = total population",
            psavert = "psavert = personal savings rate",
            uempmed = "uempmed = median duration of unemploymente",
            unemploy = "unemploy = number of unemployed")


ggplot(data = df, aes(x=variable, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(key_glyph = draw_key_blank) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rep("grey", length(labels)), labels = labels) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA),
        legend.key.width = unit(0, "pt"),
        legend.spacing.x = unit(0, "pt"))
```

[image]